# Instr, Replace and Trim in VB [Code Explanation]

Tags: vb.net, replace, trim

I am new to VB, can anyone explain this following code which is not understandable to me.
I basically learn Instr, Trim and replace but all are confused at one time which comes together.
Here Myval1 and Myval2 contains

Myval1='N-123','N-124','N-125'
Myval2=AB,BC,CD

As my understanding, StreamReader reading the path, the line declared as line, the all lines are read from the

given path and stored in line, then we maching specifice word myval1 in line as compared method as test, if the

position greater than 0 then trim, replace will happen. Here, position of Myval1= is 1 right, now the statement

after the 'Then' will process. I have confuse in this statement having ", , , " I understand Myval1, Myval2 is replaced with null("") and I dont understand about three commas, can any one explain here

```
        Dim st As StreamReader = New StreamReader(myPath)
        Dim line As String

        Do
            line = st.ReadLine()
            If InStr(line, "Myval1=", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then
                Myval1 = Trim(Replace(line, "Myval1=", "", , , CompareMethod.Text))
            End If
    If InStr(line, "MyValue=", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then
                Myval2 = Trim(Replace(line, "Myval2=", "", , , CompareMethod.Text))
            End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something missing in the code - where does the loop close? Also where are Myval1 and Myval2 declared?

**Nevertheless the code does the following:**

Read a file sequentially line by line. If a line contains the string "Myval1=" then remove that string from the line and also remove blanks at the beginning and at the end of the line (Trim). 
Keep in mind that the variable "line" itself isn't changed by that. The result of the manipulations is saved in the variable "Myval1".

The same is done afterwards if the line contains the string "Myval2="

The ", , ," in the Replace function just means that two optional parameters are not used. You could also write:

```
Myval1 = Trim(Replace(line, "Myval1=", "",vbNull,vbNull, CompareMethod.Text))
```

The first ommitted parameter allows you to define a start position when reading "line". The second one allows you define a limit how often a SubString should be replaced.

Let's assume the variable "line" looks like the following:

```
Dim line As String = "xxxMyval1=foo,Myval1=bar,Myval1=foobar"
```

The you can specify to start at the fourth position and only remove the first two occurrences of "Myval1" like this:

```
Dim result As String = Replace(line, "Myval1=", "", 4, 2, CompareMethod.Text)
Console.Write(result)
```

*Produces:*

> foo,bar,Myval1=foobar

At last:
You don't even need the optional parameter "CompareMethod.Text" as it's the default. So your Replace function can also look like this and does the same:

```
Dim result As String = Replace(line, "Myval1=", "", 4, 2)
```

Or for your original code:

```
Myval1 = Trim(Replace(line, "Myval1=", ""))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Jan, I just pick some of the code from my main code. So loop is not ended here.